# Run Software as different user

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm running my exe which removes a piece of software from the machine. My exe is ran as a service account and not my the user user who is logged on. During the uninstall explorer.exe is killed. I would like to call the explore.exe process to run as the current logged on user but I can't work out how to do this.

I have found that you can run it as a different user

*Process.Start("C:\Windows\Explorer.exe", username, password, domain)*

but I cant find how to do it as the current user and not making the user input their details.

Comment: I'm glad you're looking into doing this the right way - I've seen many apps do something similar and end up launching something afterwards with admin privileges instead of current user privileges.

Comment: "the" current logged on user doesn't exist in modern windows. *multiple* accounts can be logged in and each will have their own explorer process (also, I wonder if your kill code is taking this into account also)